# Cascading Equality Checks over Ands: System.Guid

Tags: c#

While looking at the difference between `guid.Equals(anotherGuid)` and `guid == anotherGuid`, I decompiled the .NET System.dll and saw something like (shortened and condensed:

```
if (g._a == this._a) {
    if (g._b == this._b) {
        ...
        if (g._k == this._k) { return true; }
    } else { return false; }
} else { return false; }
```

This seems, um, odd. I would have expected code like:

```
if (g._a == this._a && g._b == this._b && ...
```

Is there a reason they coded it the way they did, instead of the way I expected it?  What, if anything, is the difference here?

Comment: You do realize that decompiled code is a best attempt at restructuring the IL? It does not necessarilly correspond to the original code. If you want to know how this was implemented, you need to look at the actual source.

Comment: @Oded yes, that's obviously a given. I also know that Microsoft has been criticized for not following their own coding conventions, or something.  I'm just curious to know if there is really a difference, although I'm not expecting there to be one.

Answer (score 3):

Decompiled code is not the same as the original code so you might see differences.

The C# compiler actually translates `&&` to branching at the IL level because CIL does not have a notion of short-circuit `and`. Your decompiler did not pick that up and back-translated the IL awkwardly.

Comment: If you're postulating that it's a compiler derp, I'm not sure I agree. Similar comparisons tend to decompile as a `!(a == a || b == b || ...)`. But I don't know if there is a better answer than this. +1